# get Facebook comments of a webpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api

1. **I have an app that is connected to my Facebook page.**
2. **by using the APP id i have embedded the comments widget to several web pages on my website.**

   (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId={app_id}";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

I have the facebook comments widget installed on several web pages on my website:

Some pages for example:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.foo.bar" data-numposts="20"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.foo.bar1" data-numposts="20"></div>    
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.foo.bar2" data-numposts="20"></div>
```

**3. Now im trying to get the comments posted on the pages using facebook graph API**

I have tried these and more:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.bar2/comments
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{app_id}/comments
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/comments
```

Most of them return:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (URL)
```

Is it possible to get the comments posted on a specific webpage ? how ?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: thanks , this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: That works for me as well.